# How to send an object with file in spring rest template

Tags: spring, http, junit, multipartform-data, resttemplate

I am using Spring Boot and wrote service and controller. So, my controller looks like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addSentiment", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public @ResponseBody ResponseDto<Sentiment> add(@RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file,
        @RequestPart(value = "sentiment") Sentiment sentiment) {

    try {
        sentiment.setImage(file.getBytes());
        sentiment.setImageType(file.getOriginalFilename().split("\\.")[1]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sentiment = service.create(sentiment);
    if (sentiment != null) {

        return new ResponseDto<Sentiment>(true, sentiment);
    }
    return new ResponseDto<Sentiment>(false);
}
```

I am writing JUnit test class to test this controller. My Junit test class' function looks like

```
private Long testAddMultipartSentiment(Set<Category> prerequisiteSet) throws JsonProcessingException {
    String mapAsJson = new ObjectMapper()
            .writeValueAsString(TestDataUtils.getSentimentRequestBody(prerequisiteSet));
    LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    map.add("file", new File("H:" + File.separator + "testimage.jpg"));
    map.add("sentiment", mapAsJson);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>>(map, headers);

    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(TestUtils.BASE_URL
            + TestUtils.SENTIMENT_CONTROLLER_APIS.ADDSENTIMENT);
    HttpEntity<ResponseDto<Sentiment>> response = restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().encode().toUri(),
            HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<ResponseDto<Sentiment>>() {
            });
    ResponseDto<Sentiment> apiResponse = response.getBody();
    assertNotNull(apiResponse);
    assertTrue(apiResponse.getSuccess());
    Sentiment sentiment = (Sentiment) (response.getBody().getMessages().get(0));
    sentiment = TestDataUtils.getSentiment(sentiment.getId());
    assertNotNull(sentiment);
    return sentiment.getId();
}
```

I am getting error 400, bad request in response object. What's wrong in the HTTP request? I am not able to figure out as I am novice in web technologies.